# How to check characters in a file and if it isn't exist Paste it with GoLang?

Tags: go, if-statement

I would like to write a code with Go, that it checks if a character in the File1 exists in the File2 or not.

If it exist, skip; if it doesn't exist, write it in the file 2..

May you help me please? I couldn't paste here my code, but you can chek it from here:
https://go.dev/play/p/IX_ibwya1B1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting `[]byte` to a `map[byte]bool` lets you use the *comma ok* notation to check if a byte exits in a map.

In your example, you can convert to a map the []byte of File2 and then loop for the bytes in File1 to check if some of them exist in the map.

```
func main() {
    file1 := []byte("Hello world!")
    file2 := []byte("Say Hello!")

    m := convertToMap(file2)

    for _, v := range file1 {
        if _, ok := m[v]; !ok {
            fmt.Println(string(v))
        }
    }
}

func convertToMap(b []byte) map[byte]bool {
    m := map[byte]bool{}
    for _, v := range b {
        m[v] = true
    }
    return m
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/VktG78V324d

Comment: That is not the *comma ok* notation.

Comment: thanks for your answer; But I think you didn't understand what I meant I want to check the character from file 1. I can't enter the character manually. may you help me again?– 
I tried this code like https://go.dev/play/p/SZs2KpOJeRP but I gave errors. I'm too beginner in Golang. please help me as well as possible. Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: Hi @AliakbarSMMS, I'm sorry for not being clear enough. You can use the func ReadFile from the os library to return the content as []byte https://pkg.go.dev/os#ReadFile. Then your code should be like this: https://go.dev/play/p/_efXfYNJefb. If you execute this code directly in The Go Playground it will not work, because you can not read files from there. That's why my answer use []byte("Hello world!") instead of reading from a file. So try it locally.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness.
But I couldn't type it in my file again. I tried to do the same as the link, But I had error.
If you can help me again, I'll thanked you.
https://go.dev/play/p/P7qcvbHXimZ

Comment: May you answer me?

Comment: You have a compilation error when doing []byte(v). You are trying to convert a byte to an slice of bytes wich makes no sense. So declare a []bytes and then append there each value one by one. Check how to solve it: https://go.dev/play/p/P7qcvbHXimZ

Comment: @AliakbarSMMS BTW, the last comment seems to by out of the scope of the original question, that I think is already answered by far. As a new SO contributor I recommend you the next times do concrete questions about stuff that you don't understand. And avoid asking how to resolve your exercises.

Comment: @Xavier Egea did you read my question's title? "How to write" I didn't say "How to find".

Comment: @AliakbarSMMS Your questions’s title says “Paste”. Even thought that, you can write to a file, to console, to a buffer, etc... . BTW the solution provided in my last comment writes missing characters to a file. Did you check it? Let me "Paste" the link again :-P https://go.dev/play/p/P7qcvbHXimZ